# Azure ML platform wrongly interprets uploaded dataset

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a data set with about 7999 attributes and 39 labels, with 3339 total observations (resulting in 3339x8038 data set), and I'm trying to upload id to Azure ML platform.
I've selected the 'type' as 'tabular', encoding as 'utf-8', no row skipping, and use header from first file.
The problem is, that the headers are still not included and the data is interpreted as string with 0s, 1s, and commas (see pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/rplxz.jpg)

Am I missing something? For smaller data sets it seemed to work. My headers are A1, ... A7999 for the attributes, and L1, ... L39 for the labels.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

our system does our best guess over file settings when you try to create a dataset, but cannot guarantee perfect guesses in all cases.

In such scenarios, you should be able to adjust the settings. We had a bug with the ability to change those settings, but rolled out a fix. Can you try to change those now?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. It seems that now as I can change the file type to 'delimited', it detects the dataset properly.The whole process is freezing the page, but I understand that it is constantly under development and being upgraded :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about that. You're not doing anything wrong -- this is a known bug for which we've got a fix. We're trying to roll it out today. We'll keep you posted on when the fix is deployed and unblock you!